# Limiting has_one relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_information
end

class ContactInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my setup for a One-to-One relationship between the user and contact information table.

The issue I am encountering is when I create a new contact_information entry that points to a user that already has a existing contact_information, the new record is created including the relationship, meaning I have two contact_information records pointing to the same user, even though it is a one-to-one relationship.

Rails seems to pick the first record and returns it.

For example in irb:

```
> User.create
> ContactInformation.create(user: User.last)
> ContactInformation.create(user: User.last)
> ContactInformation.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ContactInformation id: 3, created_at: "2016-01-04 22:28:11", updated_at: "2016-01-04 22:28:11", user_id: 2>, #<ContactInformation id: 4, created_at: "2016-01-04 22:28:18", updated_at: "2016-01-04 22:28:18", user_id: 2>]>
```

Both with user_id set to 2.

The ideal scenario would be a validation failure from contact_information when a record is created for a user that already has a contact_information.

I came up with this initial custom validation method for the Contact Information model that kind of works for creation (Need to make one for update)

```
validate :check_parent, on: :create

def check_parent
    if user.contact_information.id.nil?
        errors.add(:user, "already has contact information")
    end
end
```

I am wondering if there is a more rails-y way of solving this problem? Or will I need to create a custom validator like this for all has_one relationships?

Thanks

Comment: I think if you instead use the `user.contact_info=ContactInfo.create()` it will unlink the previously linked and replace it. Not sure if you want that, because now you have an orphaned `ContactInfo`. Instead of replacing it, or adding a new one, you could just edit the existing? Or in other words: what is the use-case for this question? E.g. in a form I would always show the `has_one` as extra fields for the owner. Or I would allow multiple contact-info's to exist anyway (why only one?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options are available to you.

You could use [validates_uniqueness_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) on your `ContactInformation` model:

```
class ContactInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

However, **this will query the database to ensure that no duplicates exist on every save and could be very slow.**

Another option is to have your database handle this for you. Depending on what you're using `ActiveRecord` with, adding a uniqueness constraint on the `user_id` column of your `contact_informations` table could be valuable.

I would suggest not using `validates_uniqueness_of` if your dataset is large, otherwise it might be perfect.

Make sure you at least add an index to the `user_id` column on that table:

```
class AddIndexOnContactInformationToUserId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_index :contact_information, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a validation but you don't need a custom one:

```
class ContactInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

You may also want to add a unique index in the database for that column. It would not only make the query performant but will also protect your app against [race conditions in case you are running multiple instances of it in parallel](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

Comment: validates_uniqueness_of seems to have worked fine, thanks Jesuspc!